# Binding ресурса к KeyFrame storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как забиндить цвет анимации к локальному ресурсу:

```
<SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF74C365"/>
```

к этому ресурсу

```
ContrastBrush
```

Пробовал DynamicResource, StaticResource, но вылетает при наведении или при сборке.

---

```
    <Application.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="SystemButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                    <Style.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnter1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="{x:Null}" IsCumulative="False">
                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF74C365"/>
                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="#FF74C365"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
    </Style.Resources>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,3"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OnMouseEnter1_BeginStoryboard"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnMouseEnter1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnter1}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Name="ContrastBrush" x:Key="ContrastBrush" Color="#FF74C365"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь связать ресурс типа [`SolidColorBrush`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush?view=netframework-4.7) со свойством [`ColorKeyFrame.Value`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.colorkeyframe.value?view=netframework-4.7) типа [`Color`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.color?view=netframework-4.7).

Объявите ресурс с нужным цветом:

```
<Color x:Key="ContrastBrushColor">#FF74C365</Color>
```

Затем используйте так:

```
<SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ContrastBrushColor}"/>
```

Comment: Вызвало ошибку
'Cannot find resource named '{ContrastBrushColor}'. Resource names are case sensitive.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.SplineColorKeyFrame' in markup file'

Comment: @i4el0vek нужно объявить ресурс выше той строки, где планируете его использовать.

Comment: Спасибо, еще вопрос, во время выполнения я изменяю цвет 'ContrastBrushColor' , но в анимации он остается прежним, можно как то изменить static на dynamic?

Comment: @i4el0vek Нет, к сожалению нельзя использовать Bindings и динамические ресурсы в анимациях и объектах `StoryBoard`, если они описываются в разделе `Style` (вы получите исключение во время исполнения), так как они являются `Freezable` объектами. Смотрите [этот абзац](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx#Anchor_8) на msdn.